# ListView not working: "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'datasource.row identities')"

Tags: javascript, android, ios, listview, react-native

I am trying to just view item 'Pizza' in my ListView but I am getting a error. I have looked at a few other SO posts with the same error but I couldn't figure out the problem. How should we be setting my ListView? I have been following this [guide](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/01/the-beginners-guide-to-react-native-and_84.html) for reference. My code is as follows:

```
class MyNewAppreactold extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
        rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2,
      })
    };
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows([{ title: 'Pizza' }])
    })
  }

  _renderItem(item) {
    return (
      <ListItem item={item} />
      // <ListItem item={item} onPress={onPress} />
      // <ListItem item={item} onPress={() ==""> {}} />
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

        <StatusBar title="Grocery List" />

        <ListView datasource={this.state.dataSource}
          renderrow={this._renderItem.bind(this)}
          style={styles.listview}/>

        <ActionButton title="Add" />

      </View>
    )
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyNewAppreactold', () => MyNewAppreactold);
```

Comment: Can you make renderRow like this in your code and check  <ListView <ListView dataSource={this.state.dataSource} renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)} > </ListView>

Comment: You are using renderrow, which is all lowercase. Can you try that like above and check

Comment: @SivajeeBattina I tried renderRow. Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried change to `dataSource`?

```
<ListView 
     dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
     renderRow={(rowData) => <ListItem item={rowData} />}
/>
```

or

```
<ListView 
    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
    renderRow={this.renderRow} />
```

and then

```
renderRow(rowData) { 
    return (
        <ListItem item={item} />
    ); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PLEASE USE CORRECT PROP NAMES:
Change datasourse to dataSource and renderrow to renderRow.

This code works fine then.

```
 <ListView dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
      renderRow={this._renderItem.bind(this)}
      style={styles.listview}/>
```

Answer (score -1):

In case if anyone stumbled upon this issue,

- The "cloneWithRows" binding for the ListView won't work in "componentDidMount". You need to push it under "componentWillMount". I don't know why but I spent considerable time to figure it out :-(